# Sync two Shopify stores using API

Tags: node.js, rest, shopify, shopify-api

I'm currently working on two Shopify stores but I want to synchronize the customer accounts between these two stores.

I saw in the Shopify dev doc that there is an API to retrieve all the customers and I managed to make it work.

My problem is how can I use the JSON data returned to update my 2nd store database?

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy. I did it like this:

Download all the customers from the store you consider the source. Bulk download or using cursors, does not matter.

For each customer encountered, search the other store for the customer using the customer email for example. You either get back a record or you don't. If you do, you can update it, if you don't you can create it.

Unfortunately, as an exercise in programming there are 1001 ways to do this, and we have no idea what your skills or choices are there.